# Trailing Closure Syntax with AutoComplete

Tags: swift, xcode

Does anyone know why Xcode sometimes uses one syntax vs the other for trailing closures?

Example :

```
func someThingWithABlock(block:(() -> Void)) {

    block()

}
```

This is my preferred syntax :

```
someThingWithABlock { () -> Void in
    //
}
```

But sometimes Xcode will suddenly give me this :

```
someThingWithABlock({ () -> Void in
    //
})
```

I noticed that Xcode always prefers the second syntax when nesting :

```
someThingWithABlock { () -> Void in
    someThingWithABlock({ () -> Void in

    })
}
```

But only when nesting in another trailing closure :

```
func foo() {
    someThingWithABlock { () -> Void in
        //
    }
}
```

I know they are both essentially the same. But it has been annoying me for days and now I wanted to know more about and maybe fix it.

Comment: You could try filing a radar